# Images with text not getting aligned side by side

Tags: html, css

I want these these 3 sections to be side by side

[image: I want these these 3 sections to be side by side]

I want these three sections of the class box to be in line side by side. I don't know what is wrong with my code. I've cross checked it many time with the code from the instructor.

Thanks for your help.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Global */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* BOXES */

#boxes {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#boxes .box {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#boxes .box img {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<section id="boxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="./images/html5.png" alt="html5">
      <h3>HTML 5 Markup</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste corrupti incidunt cumque, delectus ullam</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="./images/css3.png" alt="css3">
      <h3>CSS 3 Styling</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste corrupti incidunt cumque, delectus ullam</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="./images/brush.png" alt="brush">
      <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste corrupti incidunt cumque, delectus ullam</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You dont have to add your whole code. Just the relevant parts. This would help to get an answer faster!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` in the `#boxes` selector in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be side by side you can just use flex

```
#boxes {
   margin-top: 20px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    /* Global */
    .container {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
       
    /* BOXES */
    #boxes {
      display: flex;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    #boxes .box {
      float: left;
      width: 25%;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #boxes .box img {
      width: 90px;
    }
```

```html
<section id="boxes">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="./images/html5.png" alt="html5">
          <h3>HTML 5 Markup</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste corrupti incidunt cumque, delectus ullam</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="container">
          <div class="box">
            <img src="./images/css3.png" alt="css3">
            <h3>CSS 3 Styling</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste corrupti incidunt cumque, delectus ullam</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="container">
          <div class="box">
            <img src="./images/brush.png" alt="brush">
            <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste corrupti incidunt cumque, delectus ullam</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex` to the #boxes. It will make its child to be in one row.
Learn more about `flex` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox;

```css
body {
  /*  font-family: Arial, Halvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5em; */
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Halvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

/* Global */
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button_1 {
  height: 38px;
  background: #e8491d;
  border: none;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

/*header*/
header {
  background: #35424a;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #e8491d 3px solid;
}

header a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header .highlight, header .current a {
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* showcase */
#showcase {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url("../images/showcase.jpg") no-repeat 0-400px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#showcase h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

/*NewsLetter */
#newsletter {
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background: #35424a;
}

#newsletter h1 {
  float: left;
}

#newsletter form {
  margin-top: 22px;
  float: right;
}

#newsletter input[type="email"] {
  padding: 4px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 250px;
}

/* BOXES */
#boxes {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:flex;
}

#boxes .box {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#boxes .box img {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding">
        <h1><span class="highlight">Sumanyu</span> Web design</h1>
      </div>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="current"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li class="current"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </header>

<section id="showcase">
    <div class= "container">
      <h1>Affordable professional Web Design</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste corrupti incidunt cumque, delectus ullam aut reprehenderit debitis doloremque, necessitatibus, nulla, ab fuga reiciendis rerum culpa possimus illum labore sit laudantium.</p>

      </div>
</section>

<section id="newsletter">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Subscribe to Our Newsletter</h1>
      <form class="process.php" action="index.html" method="post">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
        <button type="submit" class="button_1">Subscribe</button>
      </form>

  </div>
</section>

<section id="boxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="./images/html5.png" alt="html5">
      <h3>HTML 5 Markup</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste corrupti incidunt cumque, delectus ullam</p>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="./images/css3.png" alt="css3">
        <h3>CSS 3 Styling</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste corrupti incidunt cumque, delectus ullam</p>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="./images/brush.png" alt="brush">
        <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste corrupti incidunt cumque, delectus ullam</p>
      </div>
  </div>

</section>

<footer>
  <p>Sumanyu Sood Web Design, Copyright &copy; 2020 </p>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```